# AndroidX databinding generation is wrong

Tags: android, migration, androidx

I'm trying to migrate to androidx and i'm facing the following issue:

Databinding generates classes that includes `android.support..` instead of `androidx..`.

Does anyone have an ideea about how to replace `android.support..` with `androidx..`?

I'm using Android Studio 3.2, build gradle version is : 3.2.0.

Here is an example of bad generated imports:

```
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Switch;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.databinding.Bindable;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that binding generates classes based on bad .xml files.

Inside of .xml files were `android.support.something` instead of `androidx.something`.

This happened due to "migrate to androidx" feature which didn't replaced `android.support.something` with the new include (`androidx.something`) in the .xml files.

So to fix this you have to replace them manually.

Comment: In other words: in your xml file, replace `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` with `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`

Comment: Thanks @BojanRadivojevicBomber, i've replaced the answer with a clearly one based on your reply.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, all XMLs appeared to be in a good state. However, Android Studio had invalid generated classes in its cache. **Invalidate Caches/Restart** did the trick.

> Android Studio

```
Version: 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 8, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```